# EF Core HTML Table render very slow after SQL Dataset is returned

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, datatables-1.10

I have a Linq query that is returning data in 900 - 919ms through EF Core (over VPN).  However, once the data is returned it is taking an age (20-30 seconds) to render the HTML table.  The dataset is about 18,000 rows with 8 columns and I have implemented DataTables to paginate, filter and export.  The dataset itself is comprised of text only.

I have been trying to profile those 20-30 seconds to no great success, I just can't seem to find the route of the issue.

Has anyone faced similar issues?
Can anyone recommend a good debug methodology to understand the cause of delay?

I have logging enabled and that is not telling me anything of use, Application Insights in VS is not available to me.

Many thanks.

**Update**

Below is method.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExportGrid()
    {
        var result = await dbcontext.Timesheet.AsNoTracking()//.Take(100)
            //.Include(t => t.Program)
            //.ThenInclude(p => p.Client)
            //.Include(t => t.Task)
            //.Include(t => t.Person)
            .Where(t => !t.Deleted)
            .Select(t => new TimesheetDataViewModel
            {
                Id = t.Id,
                ClientName = t.Program.Client.Name,
                ProgramName = t.Program.Name,
                TaskType = t.Task.Name,
                TaskName = t.Name,
                TaskDescription = t.Description,
                TaskStart = t.TaskStart,
                TaskEnd = t.TaskEnd,
                Minutes = t.Minutes,
                Person = t.Person.Firstname + ' ' + t.Person.Surname
            }).ToListAsync();

        return View(result);
    }
```

Below is the DataTables code

```
var _tableId = $('#datatable_timesheet');
    var _orderColumns = [1];
    var _searchableColumns = [0,1,2];
    var _defaultSort = [1, "asc"];

    $(document).ready(function () {
        _tableId.DataTable({
            paging: true,
            ordering: true,
            info: false,
            responsive: true,
            deferRender: false,
            dom: '<"row"<"col-sm-3"l><"col-sm-6 text-center"B"><"col-sm-3"f>><"row"<"col-sm-12"tr>><"row"<"col-sm-5"i><"col-sm-7"p>>',
            buttons: true,
            lengthMenu: [
                [5, 15, 20, -1],
                [5, 15, 20, "All"] // change per page values here
            ],
            //pagingType: "bootstrap_full_number",
            language: {
                "lengthMenu": "  _MENU_ records",
                "paginate": {
                    "previous": "Prev",
                    "next": "Next",
                    "last": "Last",
                    "first": "First"
                }
            },
            columnDefs: [{  // set default column settings
                'orderable': true,
                'targets': _orderColumns
            }, {
                "searchable": true,
                "targets": _searchableColumns
            }]
            //order: _defaultSort // set first column as a default sort by asc*/
        });
    });
```

Comment: can you provide more details? you should paginate on server side only & retrieve only required data from sql server to application. processing on 18k data will take some tome depends on what you are doing with data.

Comment: Thanks Mukesh.  I have added the controller and datatables code, I hope that helps.  The rest of the page is just a simple html table with that id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will paginate on client side
for better performance you can use server side pagination - for e.g. refer article to use server side pagination.

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1011531/Using-jQuery-DataTables-with-Server-Side-Processin

Comment: Does this not just increase db runs?  If you call the db on each pageload, filter query etc.  I kind of understood that to typically be a bad thing.

Comment: nope, its better to retrieve only selected records rather then do all pagination & filter on client side. DB are made for this so dont worry. 

how many users wants to see all 18K records at once?? i think none. so its better to use db side pagination & filters - it will save network bandwidth & reduce client/browser memory load.

Comment: OK.  Will give it a try.

Comment: let me know if you find any issue while doing same.

Comment: what is interesting is that the URL generated has NO querystrings.  making the sort, search, order all fall over of course.  I will investigate why that might be.

Comment: let me know if anything i can help or you can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found this quite hard to get my head round and in case anyone else is, below is how I finally got everything working except sort for an application built using .Net Core 1.1 and Entity.Framework.Core

HTML

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="exportGrid">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Client Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Program Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Person
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Minutes
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Task Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Task Description
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Task Type
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Task Start
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Task End
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
```

JS and AJAX

```
$('#exportGrid').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: { "url": "TimesheetDataJsonObjectArray", "type": "POST" },
            columns: [
                { "data": "clientName" },
                { "data": "programName" },
                { "data": "person" },
                { "data": "minutes" },
                { "data": "taskName" },
                { "data": "taskDescription" },
                { "data": "taskType" },
                { "data": "taskStart" },
                { "data": "taskEnd" }],
            pageLength: 15,
            paging: true,
            ordering: true,
            info: true,
            responsive: true,
            deferRender: false,
            dom: '<"row"<"col-sm-3"l><"col-sm-6 text-center"B"><"col-sm-3"f>><"row"<"col-sm-12"tr>><"row"<"col-sm-5"i><"col-sm-7"p>>',
            buttons: true,
            lengthMenu: [
                [5, 15, 20, -1],
                [5, 15, 20, "All"]
            ]
        });
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> TimesheetDataJsonObjectArray(int draw, int start, int length)
    {
        var formData = HttpContext.Request.Form;
        string search = formData["search[value]"];
        var q = dbcontext.Timesheet.Where(t => !t.Deleted);
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
        {
            q = q.Where(t => t.Person.Surname.Contains(search));
        }

        var b = await q
            .Select(t => new TimesheetDataViewModel
            {
                Id = t.Id,
                ClientName = t.Program.Client.Name,
                ProgramName = t.Program.Name,
                TaskType = t.Task.Name,
                TaskName = t.Name,
                TaskDescription = t.Description,
                TaskStart = t.TaskStart,
                TaskEnd = t.TaskEnd,
                Minutes = t.Minutes,
                Person = t.Person.Firstname + ' ' + t.Person.Surname
            }).ToListAsync();

        var result = b.Skip(start).Take(length);
        DataTableData a = new DataTableData();
        a.data = result.ToList();
        a.draw = draw;
        a.recordsTotal = q.Count();
        a.recordsFiltered = q.Count();
        return Json(a);
    }
```